# Apache virtualhost with debian 8

Tags: apache, debian

I would like to configure an apache virtualhost with Debian 8

I have installed apache2

I have create a configuration in sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName wiki.domain.com
ServerAlias wiki.domain.com

DocumentRoot /home/www/htdocs/wiki/
<Directory /home/www/htdocs/wiki/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/www/logs/wiki/wiki_error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /home/www/logs/wiki/wiki_access.log combined
ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

Create a symbolic link in sites-enabled

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/wiki /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wiki
```

And reboot apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This configuration works with Debian 7 but with Debian 8 i am not redirected to my wiki directory when I use my domain wiki.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Require all granted` in the directory to allow apache to access to your directory

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easiest and recommanded way to enable a site with apache2:

```
    a2ensite wiki && service apache2 restart
```